# How to change background color of a cell in Devexpress Grid?

Tags: c#, grid, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a devexpress xtragrid with 40 columns.
I compare each cell value with other and if it is different then I want to change the cell background color.
I try with GridViewInfo but it only takes the columns that are visible on the screen.But I want to do for all the columns.(Not with RowCellStyle)
Do you have a solution for that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hook onto the RowStyle event of your xtragrid.

```
private void maintainDataControl_RowStyle(object sender, RowStyleEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowHandle >= 0)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;

        // Some condition
        if((string)view.GetRowCellValue(
            e.RowHandle, view.Columns["SomeRow"]).Equals("Some Value"))
        {
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The compare function is on a button .How can I call RowStyle event?

Comment: You can not do this on button click event. you must handle either `RowStyle` or `CustomDrawCell`. put their condition there and simply invalidate the grid after making changes to that data on button..

Answer (score 7):

You need to handle the **CustomDrawCell** of your GridView, here is a snip of code that change the color of the Name column, based on an other column valoe (age column)

```
private void gridView_CustomDrawCell(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column == colName)
        {
            var age = Convert.ToInt32(gridView.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, colAge));
            if (age < 18)
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0xFE, 0xDF, 0x98);
            else
                e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0xD2, 0xFD, 0x91);
        }
    }
```

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [Xtragrid Format conditions?](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument759)